# ARRAYFORMULA option for checking for cell values on each row of Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to use an ARRAYFORMULA check if a series of cells is blank/contains a number for each row. if all five columns of a row contain a number, I would like the check column to indicate TRUE. If any one of the five columns of a row are blank, I would like the check column to indicate FALSE.

While the current use references number values, I am interested in a potential blank value option for future cases that may include string data.

I have two working "dragdown" options using AND+ISNUMBER and NOT+OR+ISBLANK—each with an internal ARRAYFORMULA.

```
=AND(ArrayFormula(ISNUMBER(B2:F2)))

=NOT(OR(ArrayFormula(ISBLANK(B2:F2))))
```

Is there a single formula that would not require dragging when new values are added?

SAMPLE SHEET (blanks!): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M8ziq4he1oM0xiQ5JqbH2Y2t8UgkQfd8KIhmAFIesoc/edit#gid=109329290

Comment: `ISNUMBER` return `FALSE` when it is blank, so the latter criteria is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below array formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(MMULT(--(B2:F10=""),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:F2),1,1,0))>0,FALSE,TRUE))
```

If you want refer full column then use below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",IF(MMULT(--(B2:F=""),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:F2),1,1,0))>0,FALSE,TRUE)))
```

[image]